# Expo app crashing on start up after updating to SDK 36

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a React Native project that is built using Expo and we have just updated it from SDK 35 to SDK 36 but it now fails to start on both Android and iOS. On iOS it will actually crash the Expo app itself and on Android it just sits on a white screen. I assume this is an issue with one of the dependencies but I am not normally a React Native developer so I am unsure which one it could be, but possibly NetInfo based on the exception below?

Here are a couple of logs from the iOS Simulator.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber 
isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x86ab4ddf6b4312df'*** 
First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c4f02e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50b97b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c6ff94 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c53dac ___forwarding___ + 1436
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c55f38 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   Exponent                            0x00000001020ed764 -[ABI37_0_0RNCNetInfo detailsFromInterface:withState:] + 97
6   Exponent                            0x00000001020ed51c -[ABI37_0_0RNCNetInfo currentDictionaryFromUpdateState:withInterface:] + 147
7   Exponent                            0x00000001020ed44c -[ABI37_0_0RNCNetInfo getCurre<…>
```

Log 2

```
2020-09-07 08:38:42.448 [info][tid:com.facebook.ABI37_0_0React.JavaScript] │ '<decode: mismatch for [%c] got [STRING public sz:639]> next state', 'color: #4CAF50; font-weight: bold', { offline:    
{ busy: false,     
lastTransaction: 0,     
online: false,     
outbox: [],     
retryCount: 0,     
retryScheduled: false,     
netInfo: { isConnectionExpensive: null, reach: 'NONE' } },  
newCatchRecord: {},  
signIn: { authToken: undefined, isSignedIn: false, userId: undefined, refreshToken: undefined, numRefreshRetries: 0 },  
preferences: { vessels: [], gears: {}, ports: {},species: {} },  
submissions: {},  
_persist: { version: -1, rehydrated: false } }
```

And the dependencies as listed in `package.json`

```
 "dependencies": {
        "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
        "@redux-offline/redux-offline": "^2.6.0-expo.0",
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "bson": "^4.0.2",
        "expo": "^36.0.0",
        "expo-font": "~8.0.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.11",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "promise.prototype.finally": "^3.1.0",
        "react": "16.9.0",
        "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz",
        "react-native-appearance": "~0.3.1",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.5.0",
        "react-native-screens": "2.0.0-alpha.12",
        "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.3",
        "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.3.1",
        "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
        "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
        "redux-persist-transform-encrypt": "^2.0.1",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "styled-components": "^4.1.3",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "4.6.0"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by an issue in `netinfo 4.x.x` upgrading to `netinfo 5.x.x` (specifically 5.9.7) has fixed this.